# Find motion using blob detection on opencv

Tags: opencv, motion-detection

I have some problem about bgs library of opencv. I am using absdiff functions for motion analysis. The motion is not clear enough. I used threshold and other functions to achieve smooth motion. So, what is the most useful background subtract library to find motion using blob detection method?

Comment: "Useful" for what case?

Comment: thnks for answer , actually , what is the most effective method to find motion analysis using background subtract ?

Comment: Again, that depends on the case. To track 2 players moving around in a tennis court I would suggest one thing, to track cars moving around on a surveillence camera I would suggest something else. The point is: most effective.. For what scenario?

Comment: It will be used for faces detection when there are motion faces. When I use the absdiff function to detect motion , detecting face is not smooth. Scenario will detect people on street and track them faces. So I want to use motion detection with blob detection. In addition ,I dont want to use color detection. Because it is not stable , it is changed by environment condition. Sorry for my explanation. I hope , explanation is clear this time.

Comment: I would investigate Optical Flow (Lucas-Kanade) for that.

Comment: I think you mentioned about this method. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JO8XHzc6JPQ) . However , I didnt find any explanation about that. Besides , It seems for only one face tracking. Do you have any explanation or link etc about face tracking using optical flow ?

Comment: [There is a something](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html) around the Internet.

Comment: thnks to help but I need more deteails for Optical flow